# InnoDB buffer. Should I increase buffer size?

Tags: mysql, innodb

[image: Database version]

**Database monitor**

[image: Database monitor]

InnoDB and Key always 100%. How can I increase buffer size ? 
can this cause any problems or slow database speed?

**My configuration**

```
skip-external-locking
key_buffer_size = 64M
max_allowed_packet = 32M
table_open_cache = 256
sort_buffer_size = 4M
read_buffer_size = M
read_rnd_buffer_size = 10M
myisam_sort_buffer_size = 64M
thread_cache_size = 16
query_cache_size= 64M
thread_concurrency = 16

#innodb_use_native_aio = 0
innodb_file_per_table
```

Answer (score 1):

Short answer:  Set `innodb_buffer_pool_size` to 70% of *available* RAM (assuming you have more than 4GB of RAM).

Long answer:  For deeper investigation, we would need `SHOW VARIABLES`, `SHOW GLOBAL STATUS` and the RAM size.  And the buffer being "full" does not mean that things are running poorly -- it is a *cache*.